# Pointer to array of unspecified size "(*p)[]" illegal in C++ but legal in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function, pointers

I just found out that this is illegal in C++ (but legal in C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]))

int accumulate(int n, const int (*array)[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += (*array)[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 1, -40, 23, 35};
    printf("%d\n", accumulate(ARRAY_LENGTH(a), &a));
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without problems using `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic` but fails to compile using `g++`. When I try to compile it using `g++` I get these error messages:

```
main.cpp:5:37: error: parameter 'array' includes pointer to array of unknown bound 'int []'
 int accumulate(int n, int (*array)[])
                                     ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:50: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[9]' to 'int (*)[]' for argument '2' to 'int accumulate(int, int (*)[])'
     printf("%d\n", accumulate(ARRAY_LENGTH(a), &a));
```

I have been using this in my C code for a long time and I had no idea that it was illegal in C++. To me this seems like a useful way to document that a function takes an array whose size is not known before hand.

I want to know why this is legal C but invalid C++. I also wonder what it was that made the C++ committee decide to take it away (and breaking this compatibility with C).

So why is this legal C code but illegal C++ code?

Comment: Did the version of C that existed when C++ split off have arrays of unspecified size? I think you had to declare them as pointers in those days, and being able to use `[]` was a later addition.

Comment: C++ was split from C89 and the example compiles without problems using `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic` so I do not think that it was a later addition.

Comment: Note that your code should work if you convert `n` into a template parameter (`template<int n>`) and use that in the array type (`int (*array)[n]`). Also note that it is even possible (and most of the time easier) to use a reference to array instead of pointer to array: `int (&array)[n]`. Then call it with `accumulate(&a)` and let the compiler deduce `n` for you! ;)

Comment: @juanchopanza Not quite. There is an "array of unknown length" type in C++, and you can get declarations of that type with `extern`. Given `extern int a[];`, `int (*b)[] = &a;` is perfectly valid. But it's such a rare corner case that functions taking arrays of unspecified length are almost certainly a mistake. As for `int (*array)[42]`, C does not allow that to point to anything other than an array of length 42 either.

Comment: @hvd If the last thing you said is true, then gcc and clang are not C standards compliant, even in pedantic mode (IIRC, they only emit warnings for code [like this one](http://ideone.com/Nmxb1D))

Comment: @juanchopanza They indeed only emit a warning for that, and since the standard merely requires a diagnostic, the behaviour of the compilers is allowed by the standard. If you want to turn all standard-mandated diagnostics into an error, add `-pedantic-errors` to the command-line options.

Comment: @hvd Then I find it strange that both compilers emit an error in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza In C++, it's more complicated to treat it as a warning, because the standard requires it to be treated as an error during template argument substitution, so it can occur in a valid program.

Comment: The normal way of specifying a 'pointer to an array of any size' as a function parameter is `accumulate(int n, int array[])`, which is legal (and has the desired effect) in both C and C++

Comment: @elias, could you explain _why_ you chose to let the function take a pointer to array as argument? As Chris Dodd commented above, it is unnecessary in this program. It is also rather unusual, and it can therefore be confusing to experienced programmers.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Except for clarity, you should write it as `accumulate(int n, int* array)` and probably have a `const` thrown on as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Isn't clarity generally the most important thing?  `const` depends on whether you are modifying the array or not.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Too bad English is ambiguous.  Here's what I meant: "I agree with you except for one thing: `int array[]` is misleading.  For improved clarity, you should write it as `accumulate(int n, int* array)`"  And here the array is not being modified, which is why I also suggest `const`.

Comment: I have added `const` to the function parameter now.

Comment: @Barmar C's predecessor B, and "new B" which Ritchie retrospectively designated "Embryonic C", had *only* the bracket syntax `x[]` which implemented array *as* pointer. "Neonatal C" circa 1973 distinguished real but second-class array `x[]` which *converts* (in jargon "decays") to pointer `*x`, and relevant here is "rewritten" as function parameter, and this has remained unchanged since. See his HOPL2 paper at http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html .

Comment: @Barmar C had this feature since K&R1, if not earlier

Comment: @M.M You're right. Interestingly, https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html denigrates this syntax, describing it as a "living fossil" and saying that it "it serves as much to confuse the learner as to alert the reader."

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Dan Saks wrote about this in 1995](http://www.drdobbs.com/stepping-up-to-c/184403070), during the lead up to C++ standardisation:

> The committees decided that functions such as this, that accept a
>   pointer or reference to an array with unknown bound, complicate
>   declaration matching and overload resolution rules in C++. The
>   committees agreed that, since such functions have little utility and
>   are fairly uncommon, it would be simplest to just ban them. Hence, the
>   C++ draft now states:
>
> > If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form pointer to
> >     array of unknown bound of T or reference to array of unknown bound of
> >     T, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: The prohibition has been removed by [the resolution of CWG issue 393](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#393), adopted at the last committee meeting.

Answer (score 30):

C++ doesn't have C's notion of "compatible type". In C, this is a perfectly valid redeclaration of a variable:

```
extern int (*a)[];
extern int (*a)[3];
```

In C, this is a perfectly valid redeclaration of the same function:

```
extern void f();
extern void f(int);
```

In C, this is implementation-specific, but typically a valid redeclaration of the same variable:

```
enum E { A, B, C };
extern enum E a;
extern unsigned int a;
```

C++ doesn't have any of that. In C++, types are either the same, or are different, and if they are different, then there is very little concern in how different they are.

Similarly,

```
int main() {
  const char array[] = "Hello";
  const char (*pointer)[] = &array;
}
```

is valid in C, but invalid in C++: `array`, despite the `[]`, is declared as an array of length 6. `pointer` is declared as a pointer to an array of unspecified length, which is a different type. There is no implicit conversion from `const char (*)[6]` to `const char (*)[]`.

Because of that, functions taking pointers to arrays of unspecified length are pretty much useless in C++, and almost certainly a mistake on the part of the programmer. If you start from a concrete array instance, you almost always have the size already, so you cannot take its address in order to pass it to your function, because you would have a type mismatch.

And there is no need for pointers to arrays of unspecified length in your example either: the normal way to write that in C, which happens to also be valid in C++, is

```
int accumulate(int n, int *array)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

to be called as `accumulate(ARRAY_LENGTH(a), a)`.

Comment: There is an open [EWG issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4325.html#118) to permit the conversion.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, that's nice to know. I guess that if it does become permitted, it'll probably only be permitted in one direction. An implicit conversion from `char(*)[6]` to `char(*)[]` is safe, but an implicit conversion from `char(*)[]` to `char(*)[6]` is not. Because in C, there isn't even any conversion (the types are simply compatible), you can write code like `int main() { int array[6]; int (*ptr1)[] = &array; int (*ptr2)[100] = ptr1; }` which typically does not even get any compiler warning, let alone an error.