# How to fix "conflicting types" for a function and its declaration?

Tags: c, declaration

I want to pass a two-dimensional char array to a function but don't know how to declare the function before the main(). The function compiles and works well before I declare it. But after I declare it, I encounter compiling issues.

I'm using EMACS on MacBook pro. The compiler is gcc.I tried to declare my function print string various ways including

```
void printstring(int, int,char **);
```

or

```
void printstring(int, int,char *);
```

But none of them work. My Full codes are:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

void printstring(int, int,char **);

int main(){
  char word[3][6]= {"hello","world","I"};
  printstring(3,6,word);
  return 0;
}

void printstring(int n, int m, char (*w)[m]){
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%s\n",w[i]);
  }
  return;
}
```

I expected that there is no compiling error but I got one error and one warning. Details can be found below:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:9:19: warning: passing argument 3 of 'printstring' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   printstring(3,6,word);
                   ^~~~
test.c:5:6: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[6]'
 void printstring(int, int,char **);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
test.c: At top level:
test.c:13:6: error: conflicting types for 'printstring'
 void printstring(int n, int m, char (*w)[m]){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:5:6: note: previous declaration of 'printstring' was here
 void printstring(int, int,char **);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you're using a variable length array. The last argument (the list of strings) depends on the second argument (`m`). And `char **` is not suitable, as it's just a pointer on pointers. So the max dimension of the strings would be lost when iterating on the 2D array.

Use a standard forward declaration, copying exactly the real declaration if you don't want to put the function before the main one.

```
void printstring(int n, int m, char (*w)[m]);

int main(){
  char word[3][6]= {"hello","world","I"};
  printstring(3,6,word);
  return 0;
}
void printstring(int n, int m, char (*w)[m]){
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%s\n",w[i]);
  }
  return;
}
```

If you have read-only strings, I suggest that you use a standard array of constant pointers instead:

```
void printstring(int n, const char *w[]);

int main(){
  const char *word[] = {"hello","world","I"};
  printstring(3,word);
  return 0;
}
void printstring(int n, const char *w[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%s\n",w[i]);
  }
  return;
}
```

note that

```
printstring(3,word);
```

can be replaced by

```
printstring(sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]),word);
```

before array decays to pointer (that autocomputes the number of strings)

Comment: "And using const doesn't hurt too" It does, actually. We can't have const correct array pointers, unfortunately. The const ends up belonging to the pointed-at data. See [Const correctness for array pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199473/const-correctness-for-array-pointers). So I doubt your code will compile.

Comment: It compiles all right with `-Wall -Wextra`, but you're right. It just makes the pointer constants.

Comment: It's some gcc diagnostics bug. Use -pedantic-errors. https://godbolt.org/z/XgOhMp.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - `-pedantic` trips it for GCC

Comment: I'll remove the const. I like const too much. In the alternate read-only solution, `const` protects from writing efficiently

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - If it makes you feel any better, one can argue it's a language defect

Comment: @StoryTeller it does. Strings are one of the reasons I almost gave up C and use C++ for most compiled programs when python cannot help

Comment: Apparently gcc allows it as a [language extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199629/584518). clang too, it seems. This would be why the diagnostic messages are glitchy.

Answer (score 1):

The following should just work:

```
void printstring(int n, int m, char (*w)[m]);
```

The function prototype and definition should be kept identical, except maybe for certain qualifiers such as const and default arguments in C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain a name free declaration for whatever reason, you can use the `*` notation (reserved to function prototype scope) for the variably modified type

```
void printstring(int, int,char (*)[*]);
```

Still a VLA, and in fact, exactly equivalent to the notation that uses `m`. Though, ostensibly, it may convey intent not as clearly as using `m` in the forward declaration.

Comment: Eww, no please don't do this. Good practice is to have identical declaration and definition, where the declaration is prototype format with named parameters. The `*` thing from C99 is just ugly, confusing and superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

`char**` cannot be used to point at 2D arrays, it can only be used to point at the first element of a 1D array of `char*`, which is something else.

Your compiler error is from having non-matching declaration and definition. Correct code:

```
void printstring(int n, int m, char w[n][m]);

...

void printstring(int n, int m, char w[n][m]){
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you *can* write `void printstring(int n, int m, char (*w)[m])` and it is completely equivalent. But that is just harder to read, so why would you?