# How to print a few 2d arrays with a fuction?

Tags: arrays, c, printing

I'm using C and I'd like to print these matrices with the printMatrix function. It's fine when I print A and B. But, I don't know how matrix C is printed. can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printMatrix(const int A[][3],const int col);

void main()
{
    int A[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{-1,5,-9} };
    int B[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{1,0,4} };
    int C[3][2] = { {-2,1},{1,0},{5,4} };

    printf("A\n");
    printMatrix(A,2,3);
    printf("B\n"); printMatrix(B,2,3);
    printf("\n");
    printf("C\n"); printMatrix(C,3,2);
}


void printMatrix(const int A[][3], const int row,const int col)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems both related to the wrong array type. They array declaration `const int A[][3]` when part of a function decays into a pointer to the first element. In this case the first element would be an array of type `const int[3]` and a pointer to such an element is written as `const int(*)[3]`, so that's what `A` gets implicitly replaced with.

Now as it happens, C has stricter typing for pointers than it has for regular data. This means that you cannot pass a pointer to an array of a different size than `[3]`, nor can you pass a pointer to an array which doesn't have `const int` elements.

The size problem can be solved by using a pointer to variable-length array (VLA) instead. The `const` problem can't be easily solved<sup>1)</sup>, unfortunately, so the easiest solution is to simply drop const correctness. You could change your function to this and it will work:

```
void printMatrix(size_t row, size_t col, int A[row][col]);
```

(`size_t` is a more correct type than `int` to use when dealing with array sizes.)

---

<sup>1)</sup> Advanced topic: There *are* solutions that give both const correctness and type safety, but they are cumbersome. See [Const correctness for array pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199473/const-correctness-for-array-pointers), the `_Generic` based macro in the answer by chux in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But it doesn't work yet, the error is Parameter not available.(int A[row][col])  , Constant expression is required, Cannot allocate an array of constant size 0.

Comment: @XXXTELTACIO You must use a standard C compiler. It seems like you are using an obsolete non-standard one from the 1990s, such as Visual Studio. Or maybe you compiled the code as C++ by accident.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the type of argument `A` in

```
void printMatrix(const int A[][3], const int row,const int col);
```

The second dimension is expected to be **3**, but the type of `C` array is `int[3][2]`. The second dimension is **2**. The type of the argument does not match thus it will not work.

I suggest using Variable Length Arrays:

```
void printMatrix(const int row,const int col, const int A[row][col])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

now you can print any 2d `int` array as:

```
printMatrix(3,2,C);
```

### Edit

As noted in the comments the code will produce a warning.
The simple solution is dropping `const` from `A` argument:

```
void printMatrix(const int row,const int col, int A[row][col]);
```

Alternatively, one can add `const` qualifiers to arrays `A`,`B`, and `C`.

```
    const int A[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{-1,5,-9} };
    const int B[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{1,0,4} };
    const int C[3][2] = { {-2,1},{1,0},{5,4} };
```

Comment: This only solves one part of the problem and won't compile. I posted a complete answer.

Comment: @Lundin, Indeed. It produces warning in pedantic mode. Interesting finding, thanks.

Comment: The compiler must produce a diagnostic in any mode, since assigning an array-pointer-to-int to an array-pointer-to-const-int is a constraint violation.