# Why I got a warning when I pass 2D array in function with constant parameter whilst in 1D everything is normal?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have the following two similar codes
Snippet 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define W 5
#define N 9


void print_w(const char x[W] [N+1]);


int main()
{
     char words[W][N + 1]={{}};
     print_w(words);
     printf("R*E*V*E*R*E*S*E\n");
     print_w( (const char (*) [N+1]) words);
     return 0;
}



void print_w(const char x[W] [N+1]){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<W; i++) {
        printf("Word (%d) :%s\n", i, x[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 9

void printString(const char []);

int main(){
    char mystr[N + 1];
    scanf("%9s", mystr);
    printString(mystr);
    printString( (const char (*) ) mystr);
    return 0;
}

void printString(const char str[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0; str[i]!=0; i++) {
         printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
}
```

In snippet 1 I have a warning telling me that in line `print_w(words);`:

> [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'print_w' from incompatible pointer type

Implying that I have to make a typecast in `print_w( (const char (*) [N+1]) words);`

While in snippet 2 this is not the case with my code as I have performed both options without warnings.

Why there is a warning in the first example and not in the second? I suppose that passing wrong variable type (char --> const) in the function is not the case because a warning will occured also in snippet 2.

Comment: `={{}};` is invalid C.

Comment: `(const char (*) [N+1]) words` the cast is pointless, just pass `words`.

Comment: `(const char (*) ) mystr` the cast is pointless here too.

Comment: As for the warning you claim to get, I can't reproduce it. Maybe you are using an ancient C90 compiler?

Comment: @Lundin If i just pass words in the first case I wave a warning, in the second case indeed is pointless

Comment: @Lundin: The cast to `(const char (*) [N+1])` is not pointless; the compiler produces a warning for `printString(words)` but not for `printString((const char (*) [N+1]) words)`.

Comment: @Lundin: [The problem is reproducible.](https://godbolt.org/z/M87nWTobT)

Comment: This is a defect in the C standard; adhering to its wording technically renders a pointer to an array of `const char` incompatible with a pointer to an array of `char`.

Comment: Fair enough, I was using clang and it gives no diagnostic even with maximum warnings on.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understood what you said but why It isn't the case in second snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a defect in the C standard; a pointer to an array of `char` is not compatible with a pointer to an array of `const char` and may not be passed (with defined behavior) as an argument for a parameter of type pointer to an array of `const char`.

Note that after the automatic conversion of arrays, `print_w(words)` passes a pointer to an array to `print_w`, not an array of arrays, and, after the automatic adjustment of array parameters, `void print_w(const char x[W] [N+1])` declares `printString` to have a parameter of type pointer to array, not array of array. So we are concerned with the rules for pointers to arrays.

For `char (*)[N+1]` and `const char (*)[N+1]`, we first consider whether these pointer types are compatible. Per C 2018 6.7.6.1 2, for two pointer types to be compatible, they must point to compatible types.

They point to arrays, so we look 6.7.6.2 6, which says, for two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types.

For the elements, we look to 6.7.3 11, which says, for two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type. `char` and `const char` are not identically qualified, so they are not compatible, so the array types are not compatible, so the pointer types are not compatible.

Function calls allow passing arguments for parameters if an assignment to the parameter type is allowed, per C 6.5.2.2 2. Per 6.5.16.1 1, assignment allows “adding” a qualifier to the pointed-to type. For example, a pointer to `char` can be assigned to a pointer to `const char`. This is why the `void printString(const char [])` code does not yield an error or warning message. However, the rules do not allow adding a qualifier deeper in the type. So a pointer to an array of `char` cannot be assigned to a pointer to an array of `const char`.

This is a defect in the C standard. There is some work in the C committee to fix this. In [draft N2731](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2731.pdf), 6.2.5 28 says “… An array and its element type are always considered to be identically qualified.…” This could make the interpretation of the assignment that a pointer to an array of `char` is being assigned to a pointer to a `const`-qualified array of `char`, which would be allowed.

In the meantime, when you use the `-pedantic` switch, GCC is pedantic. One remedy is not to ask it to be pedantic. Another is to use an explicit cast. Another is to use Clang or another compiler.

Comment: Now that you mention it, there is also this [Const correctness for array pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199473/const-correctness-for-array-pointers). Same problem, the qualified version of `char (*)[n]` is actually `char(*const)[n]` and not `const char(*)[n])` as one would expect. Maybe this too will get fixed in C2x then?