# Why does dereferencing a pointer to string (char array) returns the whole string instead of the first character?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Since the pointer to array points to the first element of the array (having the same address), I don't understand why this happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {    
    char (*t)[] = {"test text"};
    printf("%s\n", *t + 1); // prints "est text"
}
```

Additionally, why does the following code print `2` then?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {    
    char (*t)[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("%d\n", *t + 1); // prints "2"
}
```

Comment: `%s` specifier is taking the *starting address* from the parameter list and printing everything until the first zero.

Comment: is there a way i can print the first char?

Comment: I don't understand why you have declared the string this way char ( * t)[]. You can declare it as char * or char[].why both?

Comment: @gsamaras: Warnings do not necessarily mean the code is not correct. They just tell you to be cautious. (which does not mean they should be ignored/unhandled)

Comment: What did you expect? What did you see in the debugger? What does your favourite C book say?

Comment: `char (*t)[] = {"test text"};` is an *array of pointers*, not a *pointer to an array*. `char t[] = "test text";` is an *array of type char*, where `t` is a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin damn it, my initial version of the answer was correct, I knew it! Thanks for coming in and clearing the smog! :)

Comment: Sure, the OP can dereference himself to where he wants to be, but it takes an extra dereference.

Comment: how do you declare a pointer to an array of chars? @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: `char array[] = "foo"; char* ptr; ptr = array;` @CodeFusion. Or course, as David mentioned below.

Comment: @CodeFusion When you declare an array of chars (e.g. `char t[] = "test text";`) or declare a *pointer to a string literal* (e.g. `char *t = "test text";`) `t` points to the first element. (the only difference is where the storage is created -- read-only memory section for the literal) **note:** `char t[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', '\0'};` is an equivalent declaration to the first -- just longer.

Comment: please check this and clear if what it says is wrong.
http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrary2.html
@DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Ok, let's slow down, `(*ap)[N]` declares a *pointer to an array* of `N` of whatever type comes before `(*ap)`. How do you declare an array? `char t[] = "test text";`  (initialized as a string) Now if you want another pointer to the array, and you do it `char (*pt)[] = &t;`, you are screwing yourself over because you have just created *a pointer to an array of undetermined size*. (*note:* nothing between `[]`). You have a pointer `t`, you can declare a simple pointer to `t` with `char *pt = t;` and then do `while (*pt) { printf ("char %c, remain : %s\n", *pt, pt); pt++; }` That's it.

Comment: `cdecl> explain char (*t)[];` says `declare t as pointer to array of char`. I stop here.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Pointer to array of unspecified size illegal in C++ but legal in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897646/pointer-to-array-of-unspecified-size-p-illegal-in-c-but-legal-in-c).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All other answers at the moment of writing this answer were incorrect. Moreover your question smells like an  [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in that the construct you were trying most probably wasn't what you wanted. What you'd really want to do is simply:

```
char *t = "test text";
printf("%s\n", t);  // prints "test text"
```

or

```
printf("%c\n", t[1]); // prints "e", the 2nd character in the string.
```

---

But since you wanted to understand why those things happen, and all the other explanations were wrong, here goes:

Your declaration declares `t` as a pointer to an array of char:

```
cdecl> explain char (*t)[];
declare t as pointer to array of char
```

**not an array of pointers as others have suggested.** Furthermore, the type of `*t` is incomplete, so you cannot take its size:

```
sizeof *t;
```

will result in

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘char[]’
     sizeof *t;
```

at compile time.

---

Now, when you try to initialize this with

```
 char (*t)[] = {"test text"};
```

it will warn because while `"test text"` is a *array of (constant) `char`*, here it decays to a **pointer to `char`**. Additionally, the braces there are useless; the excerpt above is equal to writing:

```
char (*t)[] = "test text";
```

Not unlike

```
int a = 42;
```

and

```
int a = {42};
```

are synonymous. This is C.

To get a pointer to array, you must use "address-of" operator on the array (the string literal!), to avoid it decaying to a pointer:

```
char (*t)[] = &"test text";
```

Now `t` is a properly initialized as a pointer to an (immutable) array of `char`. However in your case using a pointer to incorrect type didn't matter because the 2 pointers, despite being of incompatible type, pointed to the equally same address - only, one pointed to array-of-char, and the other to the first character in that array of char; and thus the observed behaviour was identical.

---

When you dereference `t`, which was pointer-to-array-of-`char`, you will get an locator value (lvalue) of array-of-`char`. An lvalue of array-of-char will then under normal circumstances decay to a pointer-to-the-first-element, as they usually do, so `*t + 1` will now point to the second character in that array; and `printf`ing that value will then print the contents of a 0-terminated string *starting from that pointer*.

The behaviour of `%s` is specified in C11 (n1570) as

> [`%s`]
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>                     element of an array of character type. ***Characters from the array are
>                     written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.*** *[...]* If the
>                     precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall
>                     contain a null character. *[...]*

*(emphasis mine.)*

---

As for your second initialization:

```
char (*t2)[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

if you compile this with a recent version GCC you will get lots of warnings by default, first:

```
test.c:10:19: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   char (*t2)[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                   ^
```

Thus `1` is converted from `int` to a pointer-to-array-of-`char` without any cast.

Then, of the remaining values, the compiler will complain:

```
y.c:10:19: note: (near initialization for ‘t2’)
y.c:10:21: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
   char (*t2)[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                      ^
```

That is, in your case the 2, 3, 4 and 5 were silently ignored.

The value of that pointer is thus now 1, e.g. on an x86 flat memory model it would point to memory location 1 (though this is naturally implementation defined):

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)t2);
```

prints (doubly implementation defined)

```
0x1
```

When you dereference this value (which is a pointer-to-array-of-char), you will get an lvalue for array-of-char that starts at memory address 1. When you add 1, this *array-of-char* lvalue will decay to a pointer-to-char, and as a result you will get `((char*)1) + 1` which is a pointer-to-`char` whose value is `2`. The type of that value can be verified from the warning generated by default by GCC (5.4.0):

```
y.c:5:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%d\n",*t2+1); //prints "2"
          ^
```

*The argument is of type `char *`*.

Now you pass a `(char*)2` as an argument to `printf`, to be converted using `%d`, which expects an `int`. This has undefined behaviour; in your case the byte pattern of `(char*)2` is sufficiently confusingly interpreted as `2` and thus it is printed.

And now one realizes that **the value printed has nothing to do with `2` in the original initializer**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char (*t2)[] = {1, 42};
    printf("%d\n", *t2 + 1);
}
```

will still print `2`, not `42`. QED.

---

Alternatively for both initializations you could have used the C99 compound literals to initialize:

```
// Warning: this code is super *evil*
char (*t)[] = &(char []) { "test text" };
char (*t2)[] = &(char []) { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Though this would probably be even *less* that which you wanted, and the resulting code does not have any chance of compiling in C89 or C++ compilers.

Comment: is there a way i can make t2 point to the first element of array {1,2,3,4,5}?

Comment: Why not just create an *array of char* initialized from the initializer `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`? E.g. `char t2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. It'll [convert to *pointer to char*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) that points to the 1st element in most cases, as Antti's answer points out.

Comment: I want pointer to be initialized explicitly. Is there a way i can or the reason i cant is because there is no memory allocated for the array?

Comment: That address-of-compound-literal-array-to-char is evil :D

Answer (score -2):

`*t` will fetch you the first element, then you add 1, and because of *pointer arithmetic* this means, advance one element, which explains why you get the second element.

Now in the first case you print with `%s`, which says print me the string (until the NULL terminator is meet), while in the second you print with `%d`, just a number.

If you would like to experience equivalent behavior print with `%c` in the first case too, which will require a cast, of course.

---

By the way, as already mentioned, one would usually not do:

```
char (*t)[] = {"test text"};
```

which creates an array of pointers, with the first element being the string, which should raise a warning:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c:4:18: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char (*)[]' with an expression of type 'char [10]'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  char (*t)[] = {"test text"};
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

As Olaf mentioned, this:

```
char (*t)[] = {&"test text"};
```

will make the warning go away, since you are now assigning the address of the string to the pointer.

Now try to think what will this print:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char (*t)[] = {&"test text"};
  printf("%s\n", *t + 1);
  printf("%c\n", *(*t + 1));

  return 0;
}
```

The first will take do what you expect, while the second needs an *extra dereference*, to actually get the character.

---

But something like this is usual:

```
char t[] = "test text";
```

or of course other approaches.

---

So, in that case, ask what this program will print?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char t[] = "test text";
  printf("%s\n", t + 1); 
  printf("%c\n", *(t + 1));
  return 0;
}
```

The first `print()` will take `t`, which because of dereferencing points to the first element of the array, i.e. the first character of the string, and then you add one to it, but because it's a pointer, it advances due to pointer *arithmetic* to the next element (because we do +1. If we did +2, it would advance 2 elements, and so on..).

Now as I explained above, `%s` will print the whole string, from the starting pointer of the `printf()`'s argument, until it reaches the NULL terminator of the string.

As a result, this will print "est text".

The second `printf()` follows the same exact philosophy, but its argument is preceded by the `*` operator, which means give me the element that is pointed, i.e. the second character of the string.

Since we use `%c`, it will just print that character, i.e. "e".

Comment: "which creates an array of pointers" - Ehm, no! It is a pointer to "array of `char`" as OP wrote. An array of pointers would be `char *a[XYZ]`. It is a typical ideom to use a 2D array.

Comment: i too thought that it is a pointer to string/array of chars. @olaf i am confused again.

Comment: Try `&"test text"` in the initialiser!

Comment: @CodeFusion, Olaf is correct, check my updated answer! Thanks Olaf again..

Comment: @CodeFusion: It is a pointer to an array of `char`! But as the index-operator and all other arithmetic work on pointers, never array, we typically  use a pointer one less a dimension that the array we use. So for a 1D array pointer to the scalar, for a 2D array pointer to 1D array of scalar, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't be specified the inner dimension?

Comment: @Bob__: That's done by the initialiser. Note it is not allowed otherwise.

Comment: I have to correct once more (last snippet): `t` does not decay to a pointer to the first entry, just because it is `t`, but because for that specific operation it is used (dereferencing) - be very precise with pointers and arrays! `t` still is an array, not a pointer! Try `sizeof(t)` (number of bytes the array uses) or `t++` (illegal on arrays, legal on pointers).

Comment: Hmm, you might want to explain, **why** `&"test text"` actually works (SCNR ;-)

Comment: @Olaf I attempted to, what do you think?

Comment: @gsamaras: Not related, but I always shiver about the term string in C (yes, use it myself sometimes). There just is no string type in C, as you know. But it is ok for me (sorry, I just needed that nitpick:-).

Comment: Oh @Olaf I know, but how else would I possibly name it? Any suggestion?

Comment: @gsamaras: Just let it be. OP seems to be aware of that matter and any other reader hopefully reads the title first anyway (I have the impression most don't read much more actually)

Comment: @CodeFusion: For the last snippet as I wrote? Certainly not. (and the size of a pointer is implementation defined, It can be anything starting from `1`)

Comment: ohh, i was running my questions last snippet. sorry. :D @Olaf

Answer (score -4):

In C, strings are just array of `char`s terminated by a `\0` character.
When you do:

```
char (*t)[] = {"test text"};
```

You're creating an array of pointers, and you fill in the first element with `"test text"`, which is a pointer to a zero-terminated `char` array the compiler will create for you. When you dereference `t` you get a pointer to the string, then you add 1 which makes it point to the second character and `%s` will print everything up to the zero terminator.

You could also write:

```
char t[] = "test text";
printf("%s\n", t + 1);
```

Or:

```
char t[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', '\0'};
printf("%s\n", t + 1);
```

Or even, if you don't want to modify the string:

```
const char *t = "test text";
printf("%s\n", t + 1);
```

To print a single character, use `%c` (passing in a `char`, not a pointer, so it would be `*(*t+1)` in your code or just `t[1]` in my examples, which is what you're doing with `%d`).