# Passing a parameter of type int(*)[] in C++

Tags: c++, c

The following program compiles in gcc but not g++:

```cpp
    void foo(int (*x)[])
    {
        // do something
    }

    int main()
    {
        int x[3];

        foo(&x);  // g++ error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int (*)[]’

        return 0;
    }
```

I am trying to use a library written in ANSI C, so I have no control over the interface of foo.

*Why is this valid C and not valid C++* has been discussed in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897646/pointer-to-array-of-unspecified-size-p-illegal-in-c-but-legal-in-c). My question is: **how can I call a function `foo` with such a declaration from C++?**

Comment: What do you think `int(*)[]` is doing "better" than simply `int*` ?

Comment: I can't speak to the legality of that in C, but a C++ compiler sees your statement `foo(&x)` as you passing an array of references, vs your definition of `foo(int (*x)[])` which accepts an array of ints. That's why no C++ compiler will compile your code in the example.

Comment: When you have a pointer to an array, the size of the array is part of the type. You can't have "pointer to any array".

Comment: @Ben Voigt I'm calling a library written in ANSI C from C++ and I don't have any control over the interface.

Comment: @alteredinstance Looks like a pointer to an array of three ints to me, not an array of references.

Comment: I suggest understanding the difference between 'pointer to array' and 'array of pointer':
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons `x` by itself is already a pointer to an array, when you reference it as `&x` the compiler sees a "reference to a pointer", which is illegal in the context of `foo(int (*x)[])`. I think `g++ error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3])’` makes it clear that the compiler sees `&x` as a reference to an array of pointers, and not a reference to an `int` array. My understanding isn't perfect though so I could be wrong here.

Comment: @alteredinstance `x` is an array, not a pointer to one, so, `&x` is indeed a pointer to that array. There's no reference nor array of pointers involved here.

Comment: The function should take 'int (*x)[3])'
https://godbolt.org/z/jxr587

Comment: @alteredinstance No, `x` is the array itself, which when passed in as an argument of a function will decay to a pointer to an int (not a pointer to an array).  By using the address-of unary operator `&`, you are getting a pointer to `x`, which is of type `int[3]`, so the pointer will be of type `int (*)[3]`, or in word-form, a pointer to an array of 3 ints.

Comment: The duplicate answers one of my questions but not the other. I will ask a new question focusing on how to call a function of this declaration from C++.

Comment: @HugoBurd I'll reopen, you can edit

Comment: @Antti Haapala thanks for the edit

Comment: In C, the `&x` in `main` has type `int (*)[3]`. The `x` parameter in `foo` has type `int (*)[]` which is a pointer to an incomplete array of `int` type. It is legal in C, but `foo` cannot do much with `x` apart from convert its value to some other type. For example, it could convert it back to the type `int (*)[3]`. It could also convert it to the type `int (*)[42]` which would be a very dangerous thing to do. The entire construct is best avoided, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following program compiles ... not g++:

This is because g++ compiles in the C++ language. And the shown program is ill-formed in the C++ language.

In particular, the problem is that the function parameter is a pointer to an array of unknown bound, but the passed argument is a pointer to an array of length 3. And latter is not implicitly convertible to the former.

> So how does one get a pointer to an unspecified array in C++ anyway?!

Example:

```
extern int arr_ext[ ];
       int arr_3  [3];

int (*ptr)[] = &arr_ext;
ptr          = reinterpret_cast<int (*)[]>(&arr_3); // †
```

† In C++ using this reinterpreted pointer is probably technically UB in any other way than to reinterpret back as pointer to array of length 3, but if the use happens within the C library, who knows... Rules across language boundary are sometimes murky.

---

By contrast in C, a pointer to one type is implicitly convertible to a pointer to another compatible type. And arrays of unknown bound are compatible with an array of any size, of same element type.

---

There appears to be an active issue to allow same implicit conversion in C++: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4325.html#118

Comment: So how does one **get** a pointer to an unspecified array in C++ anyway?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Added an example.

Comment: Is extern the only way to get a pointer to an unspecified array in C++?

Comment: @HugoBurd Reinterpret cast is another. I don't know if it would be well defined.

Comment: @HugoBurd You don't really need to pass a pointer to the array itself. Passing a pointer to its 1st element will suffice, eg: `void foo(int *x) { ... } int main() { int x[3]; foo(x); return 0; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau If the function doesn't take a pointer to the element, then you cannot pass a pointer to the element.

Comment: @RemyLebeau my question states that I don't have control over the interface of foo, so this is not an option